# Prove $(A^{T}+I)(A^{T}-I) = (A^{T}-I)(A^{T}+I)$

Tags: matrix-equations

Here $A^{T}$ is transpose matrix of $A$, $I$ is identity matrix.

Also prove

1) $(I-A)(I+A) = (I+A)(I-A)$

2) $(I-iA)(I+iA) = (I+iA)(I-iA)$

3) $(I-iA)^{-1} (I+iA)^{-1} = (I+iA)^{-1}(I-iA)^{-1}$

These properties are being used in a question I'm trying to solve, please give me a hint to prove.

Comment: What did you tried until posting this? You know you can just expand the products, and use the fact that $IA=AI$ for all matrices $I$.

Comment: Because, for any matrix $M,$ we always have $M=M?$ :D

Comment: sorry my bad. Corrected the mistake in title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all matrices $M$,
\begin{align}
(I-M)(I+M)&=\\
&=(I-M)I+(I-M)M\\
&=I\cdot I-M\cdot I+I\cdot M-M\cdot M\\
&=I-M+M-M^2\\
&=I-M^2\\
&=I\cdot I+M\cdot I-I\cdot M-M\cdot M\\
&=(I+M)I-(I+M)A\\
&=(I+M)(I-M)
\end{align}
Plugging $M=A$ gives $(1)$.

Plugging $M=iA$ gives $(2)$.

As for any invertivble $M,N$
$$MNN^{-1}M^{-1}=I=N^{-1}M^{-1}MN$$
we have
$$(MN)^{-1}=N^{-1}M^{-1}$$

Then, using $(2)$,

$$(I-iA)^{-1} (I+iA)^{-1}=\left((I-iA)\cdot(I+iA)\right)^{-1} = \left((I+iA)\cdot(I-iA)\right)^{-1} = (I+iA)^{-1}(I-iA)^{-1}$$